# resizing menu buttons for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I'm currently sorting my site out for mobile devices and small screens and I'm a bit stuck with how to size my menu. I have 8 menu buttons as part of a unordered list, as below:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menubar"><a class="menulink" href="/">Home</a></li>
..
.. total of 8 <li> menu buttons
</ul>
```

The 'menulink' a class sets each link to 128px. Times that by 8 and it lines up perfectly to my page width of 1024px. I am using @media query to target the changes and on mobile devices want there to be two lines of 4 buttons. The combined width of four buttons needs to equal the screen width I guess. How would I achieve this?

My CSS for the menu is below:

```
.menu{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;}

li.menubar{float:left;}

a.menulink{
display:block;
width:128px;
background-color:#333333;
text-align:center;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menu{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
.menu li{
width:25%;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}

.menu li a{
width:100%;
padding:20px;
font-size:20px;
background:lightgreen;

}
```

here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/82aVw/1/)**

now to fit it in smaller screen use `@media` query ... change the font size and padding amount to fit it in smaller screen
 for example

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .menu li a{
    padding:8px;
    font-size:16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better idea for making it comfortable for both computers( with bigger screen) & mobile devices(with smaller screen) is that give most of your attribute in % not in pixels( that are fixed) .
like

> width:80%;

Answer (score 1):

I would make each `li` item `width: 25%`. This will make it so that no matter what the browser width is, your `li` will always be in rows of 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBwbj/